# Is it possible to use http transcoding (to grpc) without google cloud platform? (node-grpc)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grpc, grpc-node

Sorry for the basic question (I'm new with gRPC).
Is it possible to use http transcoding without google cloud platform & endpoints?

(Referring to this article: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding)

I'm currently trying to create a mock-application and we are trying to have some sort of frontend with a UI (or can go headless browser in the beg.) that can send HTTP requests to the Extensible Service Proxy, and then ESP will transcode the HTTP request to HTTP2 so that it can be sent as a request to our gRPC services. I think K8s is a bit overkill since we'll only have a few containers (and not too familiar with deployment in k8s).

I'm trying to just use grpc-node, and want to do http mapping in ESP.
Can we just import <import "google/api/annotations.proto";> into our protofile and get this functionality of HTTP mapping?

Comment: IIRC, ESP *is* dependent on Cloud Endpoints but, the latest version uses Envoy's gRPC-HTTP transcoding and you can use Envoy yourself and without taking the Google dependency: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by DazWilkin, your best option would be to use the [Envoy Proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter).

If you are used to using Docker, there is a container of the application available [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/envoyproxy/envoy).

Regards,

Frederic